# SQL Server big tables or store data in a xml field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a .net solution with a big form with many data that the customer need to fill, like a form with many steps to fill all data we need to get.

So i was wondering if it's better (from a performance and design approach) a traditional big table with many fields, o store the data only on one field of XML type.

Example of one  "TraditionalTable":

| RecordId | CustomerId | Data 1 | Data 2.... | to Data N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | 01/01/1980 | abcd .... | 123 |
| 2 | 20 | 04/02/2004 | fgh .... | 230 |
| 3 | 10 | 05/01/1995 | xyz .... | 135 |

Example of one  "DataWithXMLField":

| RecordId | CustomerId | FormData |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | < data>< customerdetails>< borndate>01/01/1980< /borndate>< /customerdetails >< financialinfo >...." |

Answer (score 0):

I've done many systems like this and prefer to keep the data as XML (often it's a serialized object). I find this to be efficient at runtime and at design time. (See item below about binary attachments).

The following are some suggestions based on what I've done in the past. Obviously it's not a one-sized hammer...

Often data is "collected" by a user and "approved" by an administrator. While collecting the data, it's stored as XML. When approved, the XML is shred and placed into "normal" relational tables/fields.

Often this data has been collected through multiple pages. Storing as XML allows collecting data in a way that is logical to the user but doesn't fit the final data structure very well.

If a form is abandoned (not completed or canceled) it's easy to delete a single row.

Things to keep in mind:

- Some data is related to workflow and is separate from the data being collected. For example, and field for "Form Status" may go from "In Progress", to "Submitted" to "Approved". This type of data should be kept as regular columns.
- Store Binary Data separately. If your form includes submitting binary data (like uploading a PDF) I like to generate a GUID on the front end. Store that GUID in the XML and then save the binary data separately using the GUID. Possibly on disk or in a separate "attachments" table.
- Define a column for a "version number" of the XML. This way you can programmatically identify what is in the XML. This will help in the future when you need to make changes to the XML.
- Define a column for a "Summary" that is short human-friendly version of the XML. For example, if your XML contains information for registering for summer camps, your "XML Summary" might contain the text: "SMITH,JOHN, Camp White Pine 2021". This text us calculated on the front end. It can then be used for displaying rows of data without having to poke into the XML. For example, an administrative page may exist that lists applications that require approval.
- Define a column to indicate if the XML meets all your requirements. You don't want to validate XML in the database (it's often hard, and likely repetitive of the UI). Your business layer can apply business rules (Validation) to the XML (or classes) and store in the database an indicator that all business rules are met.

Comment: Thanks Robert, your answer is very complete, and give me a lot of information. about save some filed value like separate and individual columns is a good tips, kind regards.